# Using enum type in a switch statement

Tags: c, enums, switch-statement

I am using a switch statement to return from my main function early if some special case is detected. The special cases are encoded using an enum type, as shown below.

```
typedef enum {
    NEG_INF,
    ZERO,
    POS_INF,
    NOT_SPECIAL
} extrema;

int main(){

    // ...

    extrema check = POS_INF;

    switch(check){
        NEG_INF: printf("neg inf"); return 1;
        ZERO: printf("zero"); return 2;
        POS_INF: printf("pos inf"); return 3;
        default: printf("not special"); break;
    }

    // ...

    return 0;

}
```

Strangely enough, when I run this, the string `not special` is printed to the console and the rest of the main function carries on with execution.

How can I get the switch statement to function properly here? Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No `case` labels.  You've got `goto` labels now. Try:

```
switch(check){
    case NEG_INF: printf("neg inf"); return 1;
    case ZERO: printf("zero"); return 2;
    case POS_INF: printf("pos inf"); return 3;
    default: printf("not special"); break;
}
```

Comment: !! I should have seen that but I didn't.  Amazing what you can read right past and not notice.

Comment: Oh. my. God.

I've gotten so used to Verilog, I forgot all about that. This C code is a functional simulation to some Verilog project I have.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't used the keyword "case". The version given below will work fine.

```
typedef enum {
    NEG_INF,
    ZERO,
    POS_INF,
    NOT_SPECIAL

} extrema;

int main(){

    extrema check = POS_INF;

    switch(check){
        case NEG_INF: printf("neg inf"); return 1;
        case ZERO: printf("zero"); return 2;
        case POS_INF: printf("pos inf"); return 3;
        default: printf("not special"); break;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the all-important `case`:

```
switch(check){
    case NEG_INF: printf("neg inf");     return 1;
    case ZERO:    printf("zero");        return 2;
    case POS_INF: printf("pos inf");     return 3;
    default:      printf("not special"); break;
}
```

You created some (unused) labels with the same names as your enumeration constants (which is why it compiled).